# writing list of list into a COLUMNED .txt file via python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like

```
[["a","b","c","d"],["e","f","g","h"],["i","j","k","l"]]
```

How can I convert this list of list into a text file that looks like

```
a  b  c  d
e  f  g  h
i  j  k  l
```

It seemed straightforward but none of the solution on the web seemed concise and elucidating enough for dummies like me to understand.

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by columned?

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, etc. variables or do you want to print these letters?

Comment: \t (tab) might help with alignment. And if values are tab separated, they’ll paste directly into an Excel spreadsheet (should you want to do that!).

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting just to highlight the steps you need to take

```
l = [['a','b','c','d'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for sub_list in l:
        for elem in sub_list:
            f.write(elem + ' ')
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: While this surely works, it is rather inefficient to call `write()` so often.

Answer (score 6):

Praise the power of comprehensions here:

```
lst = [["a","b","c","d"],["e","f","g","h"],["i","j","k","l"]]

out = "\n".join([" ".join(sublist) for sublist in lst])
print(out)
```

This yields

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
```

Or, longer, maybe more understandable:

```
for sublist in lst:
    line = " ".join(sublist)
    print(line)
```

---

If your elements have different lengths, you could leverage `.format()`:

```
lst = [["a","b","cde","d"],["e","f","g","h"],["i","j","k","l"]]

out = "\n".join(["".join("{:>5}".format(item) for item in sublst) for sublst in lst])
print(out)
```

Which would yield

```
a    b  cde    d
e    f    g    h
i    j    k    l
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension with newline:

```
'\n'.join(' '.join(item) for item in ls)
```

Answer (score 2):

To write in a file in that format you can use `join` like this :

```
array = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j','k','l']]

# create a file if not exist and open it
file = open('testfile.txt', 'w')

# for each element in the array
for a in array: 
    # convert each sub list to a string, and write it in the file, note break line '\n'
    file.write(' '.join(a) + '\n') 

# close the file when you finish
file.close()
```

result :

[image: write in a file]

---

To avoid the break line in the end you can use :

```
breakLine = ''
for a in array:
    file.write(breakLine + ' '.join(a))
    # Use break line after the first write
    breakLine = '\n'
file.close()
```

result 2

[image: write in a file]

Answer (score 1):

There's csv for that.

```
l = [["a","b","c","d"],["e","f","g","h"],["i","j","k","l"]]

with open("test.csv", 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')# or "\t", default is coma.
    writer.writerows(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

More one liners, for fun
(Don't write code like this btw!)

`with open('/tmp/my_file2.txt', 'w') as thefile: thefile.write('\n'.join(' '.join(el for el in l1) for sub in sub))`